# How to find the available audio routes in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, avaudiosession, audio-route

I am new to iOS, i have a problem which need to find the available audio routes in iPhone (iOS7)? (like if headphone is connected it should be both iPhone and headphone,if Bluetooth and headphone is connected it should
 be all the three).

I have tried `[[AudioSession sharedInstance]current route].outputs`, but it is giving the current route(currently
active route) details only, i have also tried the outputDataSources property of audioSession, but it is giving nil value.
Can anyone suggest a proper solution for this if apple is exposing API's for finding the available routes.